# Why Border disappear when setting big Width?

Tags: c#, wpf

I resize the border according to timeline. Why when the `Width` becomes very big the `Border` disappear. For example for `Width=100000` the `Border` is visible but for `Width=200000` the `Border` disappears.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black"  Height="100" Width="1000000">
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Why do you need `Border` such a size?

Comment: I create digital signal with it. When it's low I use `BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"` when it's high I use `BorderThickness="1,1,1,0"`. Anyway, what is the reason it disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that there are some limitations on the `Border` setting *`BorderThickness`* property. 
Unfortunately, I can not say exactly how they look, I tried to find them using [`ILSpy`](http://ilspy.net) (you can try to look for them am).

One limitation I can say: if the value of one coordinate over *`125,000`* the line of `Border` disappears. Here is my list of examples:

```
Thickness    Width
---------  ---------
 0,0,0,1    125 001
 0,0,0,2    251 000
 0,0,0,3    375 001
 0,0,0,4    501 000
```

In all these cases, the line is not drawn.

As an alternative, you can increase the value for Thickness  each time (not varinat), or using a [`Line`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.line%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [`Separator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.separator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for them, there should be no restrictions. You need to change the value of `Margin`, depending on conditions or setting the `Visibility` for him.

Example with `Separator`:

```
<Separator Name="HighSignal"
           Width="1000000"
           Background="Black" 
           Height="2"
           Visibility="Collapsed"
           Margin="0,100,0,0" />

<Separator Name="LowSignal"
           Width="1000000" 
           Background="Black"
           Height="2"
           Visibility="Visible"
           Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```

**`Note:`** For Separator you may create a `Style`, because for him base type a Control (for Line -`Shape`).